# Dominated convergence theorem with Lipschitz function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, vector-spaces, lebesgue-measure

Let $\varphi\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a Lipschitz function.

Let $\nu\in\mathbb{R}^n$ with $||\nu||=1$ and let $t\in\mathbb{R}$ ($t=\frac{1}{n}$ for convenience).

I want to major the function $\biggl\lvert \displaystyle\frac{\varphi(x+t\nu)-\varphi(x)}{t}f(x)\biggr\rvert$ with an $L^1$ function for applying the Dominated Convergence theorem in the limit $\lim\limits_{t\to 0} \displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\frac{\varphi(x+t\nu)-\varphi(x)}{t}f(x)\,\ dx$.
How would I do this?

I think that $\varphi\in C^1$ implies that $\varphi$ is locally Lipschitz but $\varphi$ has compact support and then $\varphi$ is $L$-Lipschitz.
Then $\biggl\lvert \displaystyle\frac{\varphi(x+t\nu)-\varphi(x)}{t}\biggr\rvert\le L$ but how would I control $f(x)$? Maybe I should work in support of $\varphi(x+t\nu)-\varphi(x)$ [is this function in $C_c(\mathbb{R}^n$)?].

Answer (score 1):

There is some $L$ such that $\|D \phi(x)\| \le L$ and so
$|{ \phi( x+t \nu)-\phi(x) \over t} | \le L \|\nu\|=L$.

If $|s| \le 1$ then there is some compact $K$ such that if $x \notin K$ then  $\phi(x+s \nu) = 0$ for all $|s| \le 1$.

Since $f$ is Lipschitz, it is continuous on $K$, hence bounded by some $F$ on $K$ (and measurable, of course).

Hence $|{ \phi( x+t \nu)-\phi(x) \over t} f(x)| \le L \, F\, 1_K(x)$, and the latter is integrable.

Comment: Can you explicit the compact $K$ in function of $supp(f)$, please?

Comment: I do not understand your question.

Comment: Who is $K$? How can i construct $K$?

Comment: What does the $c$ in $C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ mean to you???